# Mysql - Make combination of two columns unique

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a mysql database table with two columns of importance, the `university_id` column and `username` column. <strike>Here the university_id should be unique to the whole table, but</strike> the two columns can repeat many times but the same combinations must not repeat, the username should be unique only to the university_id. here is what i mean

```
 id   university_id     username
 1       10001           DrDre
 2       10002          slimshady
 3       10003          slimshady
 4       10004           DrDre
 5       10005           lilwyn
 6       10005           lilwyn <- only this line would be illegal 
 7       10005          kanyeEast
```

- if possible i would also like to know how to do it using doctrine in symfony2

-thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below alter statement if you did not make any constraint on table-

```
alter table mytable 
add unique key Uk_university_id(university_id), 
add unique key Uk_unvid_username(university_id,username);
```

Update:

```
alter table mytable  
add unique key Uk_unvid_username(university_id,username);
```

Comment: yes it is fine as university_id should be unique for whole table as you mentioned in your post.

Comment: but in your example you need just unique based on combination, so use alter as per my new update.

Comment: it's more of a question problem with his shown data

Comment: now you can just drop first key as "alter table mytable drop key Uk_university_id;"

Comment: @ZafarMalik OP here, i am sorry, i may have worded the question wrongly, i have edited it, the example table structure is exactly what i need. i hope i was clear this time around :)

Comment: Create unique key as per Update in my answer if there is no unique key constraint on table if you have created as I suggested earlier then drop 1st key as I mentioned in my above comments...it will fulfill your requirement.