# How to make combination of two columns unique in Symfony 4 using Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a table named 'student_assignment' in which I have multiple columns from which I am showing 2 of them below:

Both of these columns are also foreign keys.

```
StudentId   assignmentId
    10           7           -> allowed
    10           8           -> allowed
    11           7           -> allowed
    11           7           -> not allowed, the combination of 11 7 already exists in table
```

I have tried this in my entity file, but it does not work.

```
/**
 * Webkul\CampusConnect\Entity\StudentAssignment
 *
 * @Table(name="student_assignment", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="assignment_unique", 
 *            columns={"student", "assignment"})
 *    }
 * )
 * @Entity
 */
```

Please how to implement this using ORM in symfony 4.

I have a link which does ther same but in Mysql. I want the solution for Symfony ORM.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204012/mysql-make-combination-of-two-columns-unique)

**Error:**

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Table" in class
>   Webkul\CampusConnect\En     tity\StudentAssignment was never imported.
>   Did you maybe forget to add a "u     se" statement for this
>   annotation?

**Entity:**

```
namespace Webkul\CampusConnect\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

/**
 * Webkul\CampusConnect\Entity\StudentAssignment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="student_assignment", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="assignment_unique", 
 *            columns={"student", "assignment"})
 *    }
 * )
 * @Entity
 */
class StudentAssignment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Webkul\CampusConnect\Entity\Student", inversedBy="studentAssignments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $student;
```

Comment: did you update your database after implementing this? or try to clear cache

Comment: @habibun: The above gives me error. I have updated the question with error. Please check.

Comment: please put after namespace,

`use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;`

Comment: @habibun: I have used it. I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: clear cache try again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've edited, but you weren't using `ORM` as an imported alias, that was number 1 (see comments).

Then you missed adding `ORM` to the inner configuration, e.g. `@ORM\UniqueConstraint` instead of `@UniqueConstraint`. Also, the configuration of UniqueConstraint requires the use of the **column** names, not **property**.

You've not provided both sides of the join table'esque OtM - MtO relation, but I'll assume it exists. You should have:

```php
namespace Webkul\CampusConnect\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *    name="student_assignment", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="assignment_unique", columns={"student_id", "assignment_id"})
 *    }
 * )
 * @Entity
 */
class StudentAssignment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Webkul\CampusConnect\Entity\Student", inversedBy="studentAssignments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $student;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Webkul\CampusConnect\Entity\Assignment", inversedBy="studentAssignments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="assignment_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $assignment;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Symfony ≥5.2 (and Doctrine ORM ≥2.9) solution with attributes:

```
<?php
// ...

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity; // optional, see below

//  ...

#[ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: 'foo_bar', columns: ['foo', 'bar', 'user_id'])] // notice the "_id" suffix in the relation column
#[UniqueEntity(['foo', 'bar', 'user'])] // optional Symfony-level constraint: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html
class FoobarEntity
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $foo;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $bar;

    // relation example
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'userFoobars')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $user = null;
 
    // ...
}
```